# What does it mean when the docs say an interface must be initialized?

Tags: c#, .net

I am a junior developer who has been working with C# for the past few months. I have been going over some of the fundamentals again by reading [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/) and came across a sentence that has some wording I find confusing. The documentation states:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
MyClass mc2 = mc;
```

> An interface must be initialized together with a class object that implements it. If MyClass implements IMyInterface, you create an instance of IMyInterface as shown in the following example:

```
IMyInterface iface = new MyClass();
```

Saying "an interface must be initialized" and "you create an instance of IMyInterface" doesn't make much sense to me, and this is not something I have had to do yet.

To my understanding, MyClass would implement IMyInterface and could then, for example, be passed into a method somewhere that expects an IMyInterface parameter. Since MyClass would have to implement all the necessary interface methods, it would hold up its side of the 'contract' and the method that expects an IMyInterface parameter would be able to interact with it as it pleases (treating it as an IMyInterface at 'surface' level, even though it is an instance of MyClass).

Where does initialising an interface come into play? Am I misunderstanding this sentence and is the documentation perhaps instead saying that

```
IMyInterface iface = new MyClass();
```

is what happens implicitly when initialising an object of a class that implements this interface?

I am quite confused as to why this talks about initialising an interface when, in my mind, that defeats the point of an interface.

Comment: Presumably [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/#reference-types)? It really would be more helpful for you to include such a link (if that's the right one, or a different one) *in your question*, so that others can see more of the surrounding context than just the words you've picked out.

Comment: That statement, by itself, does seem unnecessarily confusing.  All that line of code is doing is creating an instance of `MyClass` and storing a reference to that instance in a variable of type `IMyInterface`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, I have added a link to the documentation. To be honest though, there really isn't much context to this statement in the documentation. It seems to just state this and move on, which makes even less sense to me

Comment: I suspect that it's trying, really badly, to state that you cannot "`new` up" an interface directly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not quite sure how to mark this as the answer but I think this is exactly it

Comment: Well, I've raised this [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/26396) for the document, because whatever it is trying to say, it's not clear.

Comment: Pretty poor wording IMO

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm happy with the understanding that all they're saying is that one can't initialise an interface like so:

```
IMyInterface iface = new IMyInterface();
```

and instead it must always be initialised using a class that implements the interface:

```
IMyInterface iface = new ClassThatImplementsThisInterface();
```

I think I might have read into it a bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an interface means to create a class that derives from the interface.
To my understanding it the line `IMyInterface iface = new MyClass();` can be seen both as instantiating an instance of `MyClass` and as instantiating an instance of interface `IMyInterface`. Of course `MyClass` needs to implement `IMyInterface` for this to be valid.

Comment: "MyClass needs to inherit from IMyInterface for this to be valid."  "Inherit from" and "implement" are two different things.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand that this is what it is doing, but I think I might just be tripping myself up by over analysing the wording.

Maybe the documentation is saying, if you wish to initialise an interface, it must be done using an instance of a class that implements the interface, which I suppose goes without saying. Maybe I'm just nitpicking a bit too much

Comment: There is nothing wrong about being a nit pick when trying to learn a programming language. For the beginner the concepts are new and of course it makes the learning easier if the documentation uses consistent and understandable vocabulary. Learning programming languages is also a bit like trying to learn a real language; it is bound to be misunderstandings in the beginning.

Comment: @Duston of course you are right. I have changed to "implement"